# how to multiline comment in ruby rspec (watir or watir-webdriver) script?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I know "#" is for single line
and in ruby, the multiline comment signal is
=begin
xxxx
=end

but is doesn't work in watir/watir-webdriver +rspec script

```
describe "IAchecklist" do

=begin
 xxxx
=end
end
```

so I know how to multiline comment ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `=begin` and `=end` have to start from beginning of the line(0 column). Even if the code is nested.

Comment: I didn't get the point *beginning of the line(0 column)*.. :( Help me to understand..

Comment: @ArupRakshit the equals sign should be all the way to the left (touching the left edge of the page)

Comment: @JeremyMoritz Thank you. :)